# Python Singleton objects with the same attribute should reference to the same object

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I want Python to return the same object when the instances are created with the similar attributes. Also when I am changing some attribute of one instance, that attribute should be synchronized between other instances also.

```py
class Session:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id 
        self.data = None

session1 = Session(1)
session1.data = 202
print(session1.data) # 202
print(id(session1)) # should be 1111

session11 = Session(1)
print(session11.data) # 202
print(id(session11)) # should be the same as session1 -> 1111

session2 = Session(2)
print(id(session2)) # 2222
```

You can see above that I want `session1` and `session1a` be the same object because of `Session(1)`, while `session2` is another object because of `Session(2)`.

How could I do it?

Comment: Note that this may be unexpected behavior, as objects don’t usually behave this way. At least using an explicit alternative constructor would make this clearer, e.g.: `Session.singleton(1)`. Also note that this behavior prevents garbage collecting objects if you need to keep them around…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python)

Comment: @aaossa I have read that article but could not found an answer

Comment: @deceze I didn't understand what you mean by `Session.singleton(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `__new__` method to return a cached object for the same parameters.

A [weakref.WeakValueDictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary) is an appropriate data structure for storing your cached objects, when objects are deleted they will be garbage collected rather than persisting because your cache references them

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary


class Session:

    _cache = WeakValueDictionary()

    def __new__(cls, id):
        obj = cls._cache.get(id)
        if not obj:
            obj = object.__new__(cls)
            cls._cache[id] = obj
        return obj

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
```

The same object will be returned for the same `id`

```
s1 = Session(1)
print(id(s1))  # 4532746224
s2 = Session(1)
print(id(s2))  # 4532746224
s3 = Session(2)
print(id(s3))  # 4534405248
```

Comment: Sorry, after some tries I have noticed that it is not working, when I am changing some attribute of one class, that attribute is not being sync

Comment: How are you changing the attribute of an object where it's not working, can you add an example to the question? A quick bit of testing using my example and when I add/change an attribute on `s1` it is reflected on `s2`

Comment: I have added, check it out now

Comment: Yes I understand what you did. First of all change the attribute, then create a new instance, then check if they have the same values for attributes. They DON'T

Comment: @Rustam-Z I see what you mean, unfortunately the `__init__` method gets called every time even when returning the same object, and in your `__init__` method data gets set to None. There is probably a way to skip the `__init__` method but a bit of a hacky work around could be to use `self.data = getattr(self, 'data', None)` in your `__init__` method

Comment: `self.data = getattr(self, 'data', None)` works fine, thank you Iain!

Comment: Can we achieve it using python decorator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71103429/multiple-python-singleton-class-objects-with-the-same-attribute-should-reference